# ChildComponent not changing after input attribute changes Angular 6

Tags: parent-child, angular6

I'm passing an array from parent to child.

My parent component looks like this

```
    ...
   <app-content-order-detail-grid [stocks]="stocks" [styleSet]="600"></app- 
   content-order-detail-grid>
   ....
```

Below is my child component:

```
 .....
 export class ContentOrderDetailGridComponent implements  OnInit {
 @Input() stocks: Stock[];
 @Input() styleSet = '';
 .......
```

As soon as my **stocks** property in Parent component changes the Child does not reflect any changes. I have implemented it in other pages, it works but does not seems to work on this particular component. Have tried various ways even ngOnChanges does not reflect any changes. Is there something wrong with the data which is getting modified on certain event of calculation later in the parent

Answer (score 0):

There must be something you are doing wrong. Please check the following scenarios.

1. Check if you are initializing **stocks** input property in your child component 
   in a constructor or any lifecycle method.
2. Check **stocks** input property in **ngOnChanges** lifecycle method. Check if it is changing value as you update the parent property.
3. Make sure you are binding and updating the same parent **stocks** property to the child **stocks** property.

Even if this doesn't work, provide some more code about how do you update the parent **stocks** property.